# Construct object with name: value pairs off of n elements with [name="value"] attributes

Tags: javascript

What is a simple way to construct

```
{ 
type: [ "company", "product", "service" ]
}
```

out of:

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="company">Company
<input type="radio" name="type" value="product">Product
<input type="radio" name="type" value="service">Service
```

Using any library such as jQuery or Underscore.js, or plain JavaScript?

**A little explanation, since it seems to be confusing:**

Construct the object dynamically. That means that these HTML elements will produce the object shown, but if the name attribute was "profile", and the values were different, the result would be:

```
{ 
profile: [ "profile1", "profile2", "profile3" ]
}
```

Comment: could you use more words to explain what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it fairly easily using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):

```
function getInputValues(name)
{
    return $('input[name="' + name + '"]').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
}

var data = { 
    type: getInputValues('type')
};
```

With native JavaScript:

```
function getInputValues(name)
{
    return [].map.call(document.getElementsByName(name), function(item) {
        return item.value;
    });
}
```

Though, this assumes that the name you pass is always an `<input>` element; if that's a concern you should use a query selector instead.

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/megag/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-jQuery solution

```
var inputs = querySelectorAll("input[name=type]");

var obj = {};

obj.type = [].map.call(inputs, function(elem) {
  return elem.value;
});
```